# How to retrieve youtube comments from a specific video using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, youtube, youtube-api

I have set up everything according from the guide here : https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/eclipse

From there on, how do I start to retrieve the comments?
I'm sort of a beginner so it would be great if anyone could provide some codes to start off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should download libraries and install required libraries shown in the page your link has.

To get comments from a youtube video you should send this URL : http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments

```
    YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(
            YOUR_CLIENT_ID);
    String url="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments";    
    VideoEntry videoEntry = service.getEntry(new URL(url),
                        VideoEntry.class);        
    String commentUrl = videoEntry.getComments().getFeedLink().getHref();
    CommentFeed commentFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(commentUrl),
                    CommentFeed.class);
    for (CommentEntry comment : commentFeed.getEntries()) {
                System.out.println(comment.getPlainTextContent());
        }
```

You can get last 25 comments via this code. If you want to get more than 25 comments, you should read about pagination, max-results, start-index parameters.

Comment: May I know what's the field YOUR_CLIENT_ID for?

Comment: You should register your application to Google. First create a project in "Google Api Console" and find your client id in there. For more information, read it [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#OAuth2_Register). If you have sub-questions, search on Google, if you dont find answer, write here, we may answer.

Comment: Why is the "service" underlined red and says that it cannot be resolved?

Comment: Because, I think you have not installed required libraries into your eclipse, have you? You should download src one from this link https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list and install to your eclipse project. If you do not know how to do, just search on google. And if you agree that my answer is helpful to you, click the check sign which is in the side of my answer ;)